# Can I use FlatFileItemWriter to write multi-format file in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch, itemwriter, itemprocessor

I'm reading a multi-format file using `FlatFileItemReader` and mapping every line to its corresponding bean type in `ItemProcessor` and performing data enrichment. But when I try to write these records into a file using `FlatFileItemWriter`, I'm not able to assign separate `BeanWrapperFieldExtractor` for the different record types. How can I sort this out?

**Input File format**

```
1#9999999#00001#2#RecordType1
2#00002#June#Statement#2020#9#RecordType2
3#7777777#RecordType3
```

**Expected output file format**

```
1#9999999#00001#2#RecordType1#mobilenumber1
2#00002#June#Statement#2020#9#RecordType2#mobilenumber2
3#7777777#RecordType3#mobilenumber3
```

**ItemProcessor**

````
public class RecordTypeItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<RecordType, RecordType> {

    @Override
    public RecordType process(RecordType recordType) throws Exception {
        if (recordType instanceof RecordType1) {
            RecordType1 recordType1 = (RecordType1) recordType;
            //enrichment logic
            return recordType1;
        } else if (recordType instanceof RecordType2) {
            RecordType2 recordType2 = (RecordType2) recordType;
            //enrichment logic
            return recordType2;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor` with a `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` for that. The idea is to classify items according to their type using a `Classifier` and call the corresponding item processor/writer. This approach is cleaner IMO than using multiple `instance of` checks in the processor/writer.

There are some built-in `Classifier` implementations (I think `SubclassClassifier` is a good option for you), but you can create your own if needed.

You can find examples in [ClassifierCompositeItemProcessorTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessorTests.java) and [ClassifierCompositeItemWriterTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriterTests.java).

Comment: Will post here after I implement a working solution using this approach. Thank you Mahmoud, much appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar situation (1 input -> multiple outputs from 1 input -> 1 output file, but with different formats inside of the same file). I know the @Order annotation works great when you use a chunk size of 1, but is there a way to implement that same level of output ordering while also chunking by a larger size (50 - 100)?

Comment: I was alternatively hoping i could just manually sort it and write it afterwards, but the flatfile is always ordered by the whole chunk regardless, so even a "write as we hit it" type of method might work fine assuming i sort it manually first.

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by Mahmoud finally worked :) However, there are a few caveats. `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` is designed to write into different files. i.e., if there are 3 different Record Types, there will be 3 different output files. But in my use case, I'm expecting the output in a single file in the same order. So, I mentioned the same file name in each Writer bean and added `writer.setAppendAllowed(true); But after this, different Record Types were clubbed together and the sorting order changed. So, I reduced the chunk size from 50 to 3. 3 is the total number of Record Types. This will take a hit on the performance, however. With some tweaks like this, finally I'm getting the desired output. Here is my implementation (Just for reference, needs more cleanup)

**Configuration.java** (StepBuilderFactory)

`...chunk(3).reader(reader).processor(processor()).writer(writer).stream(recordType1FlatFileItemWriter()).stream(recordType2FlatFileItemWriter()).build();`

**Processor Step**

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemProcessor processor() {
            ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<? extends RecordType, ? extends RecordType> processor = new ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<>();
            ItemProcessor<RecordType1, RecordType1> recordType1Processor = new ItemProcessor<RecordType1, RecordType1>() {
                @Nullable
                @Override
                public RecordType1 process(RecordType1 recordType1) throws Exception {
                    //Processing logic
                    return recordType1;
                }
            };

            ItemProcessor<RecordType2, RecordType2> recordType2Processor = new ItemProcessor<RecordType2, RecordType2>() {
                @Nullable
                @Override
                public RecordType2 process(RecordType2 recordType2) throws Exception {
                    //Processing logic
                    return recordType2;
                }
            };

        SubclassClassifier classifier = new SubclassClassifier();
        Map typeMap = new HashMap();
        typeMap.put(RecordType1.class, recordType1Processor);
        typeMap.put(RecordType2.class, recordType2Processor);
        classifier.setTypeMap(typeMap);
        processor.setClassifier(classifier);
        return processor;
    }
```

**Writer Step**

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter writer(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}") Resource file) throws Exception {
        ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<String> writer = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<>();
        SubclassClassifier classifier = new SubclassClassifier<>();
        Map typeMap = new HashMap<>();
        typeMap.put(RecordType1.class, recordType1FlatFileItemWriter());
        typeMap.put(RecordType2.class, recordType2FlatFileItemWriter());
        typeMap.put(RecordType3.class, recordType3FlatFileItemWriter());
        classifier.setTypeMap(typeMap);
        writer.setClassifier(classifier);
        return writer;
    }
```

**Writer**

```
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<RecordType1> recordType1FlatFileItemWriter() throws Exception{
        FlatFileItemWriter<RecordType1> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource( new FileSystemResource(outputFolder + "test.txt"));
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<RecordType1>() {{
            setDelimiter("#");
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<RecordType1>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "RecordType", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3");
                }
            });
        }});
        return  writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<RecordType2> recordType2FlatFileItemWriter() throws Exception{
        FlatFileItemWriter<RecordType2> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource( new FileSystemResource(outputFolder + "test.txt"));
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<RecordType2>() {{
            setDelimiter("#");
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<RecordType2>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "RecordType", "ID9", "ID8",);
                }
            });
        }});
        return  writer;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, the above solution worked great. But I'm not able to pass the Filename dynamically in ```StepBuilderFactory``` stream to the ```FlatFileItemWriter```. In my scenario there will be multiple multi-format files as input and the same number of files will be generated as output with the same filename. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You can use a step-scoped writer (or a job scoped step) and late-bind the filename from a job parameter. Take a look at this section from the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding